# taskSelectAll ignores focus

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2009, ax

```
#define.taskSelectAll(778)
element.task(#taskSelectAll);
```

If I have more than one grid, the task always selects the same griddata altough the focus is on another grid. Is there a way to set the focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the grid's `AutoDeclaration = Yes` then call this code, replacing `grid1` with your actual grid control:

```
#define.taskSelectAll(778)

element.selectControl(grid1);
element.task(#taskSelectAll);
```

**OR** if you don't want to set the `AutoDeclaration = Yes` and avoid the added overhead, you can do this:

```
#define.taskSelectAll(778)

element.selectControl(element.control(element.controlId('Grid1')));
element.task(#taskSelectAll);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using method [`FormDataSource.markRecord()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa604969%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) to select required(*/all*) records?

Comment: I just want the data of the grid. This means that there could be multiple datasources on the grid.

Comment: Each grid has a property named `DataSource`. E.g. it's set to *EmplTable*, and the grid displays 2 records. In this case call `EmplTable_ds.markRecord(RecId1, 1); EmplTable_ds.markRecord(RecId2, 1);` - it will select 2 records in the grid with property `DataSource` = *EmplTable*.